# Как получить веб страницу Docker контейнера из другого контейнера?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Разбираюсь с докером. Сделал 2 сервиса в `docker-compose.yml`. И мне нужно, чтобы я со второго сервиса мог попадать на ip адреса первого. Но я не могу понять, почему это не работает. Вроде сети установлены одинаково.

Пробовал из контейнера второго сервиса вызывать `curl localhost:8080`, но он не работает. Пишет `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "curl": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`.

Скорее всего, если будет работать `curl`, то и сервис сможет получить веб страничку первого. Но пока не могу понять, почему не получается установить `curl` во второй сервис через терминал контейнера. После `apt-get install curl` пишет

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  app1:
    build: .
    hostname: app1
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - net

  app2:
    hostname: app2
    image: image/image:latest
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    container_name: app2
    networks:
      - net

networks:
  net:
```

Comment: а какой на самом деле у вас там образ `image/image:latest`?